# Mule: Remote Dispatcher fails on Deserialization at the Server

Tags: java, mule

We have a Mule Service running on a server. I am developing a stand alone Mule Client that connects directly into the Mule service.

When I run the client, I am receiving the below error:

```
    ERROR 2015-09-23 10:36:02,724 [[cheetah-web-services].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to transform from "byte[]" to "Object"
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
Transformer           : ByteArrayToMuleMessage{this=1574dd9, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.MuleMessage, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}]}
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. com.mycompany.myapp.service.model.ServiceSearch; class invalid for deserialization (java.io.InvalidClassException)
  java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo:150 (null)
2. java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mycompany.myapp.service.model.ServiceSearch; class invalid for deserialization (org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException)
  org.mule.util.SerializationUtils:85 (null)
3. Failed to transform from "byte[]" to "Object" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.transformer.simple.ByteArrayToSerializable:54 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mycompany.myapp.service.model.ServiceSearch; class invalid for deserialization
```

I have setup a remote dispatcher agent on the server.

```
  <client:remote-dispatcher-agent>
<client:remote-endpoint address="http://localhost:20809" exchange-pattern="request-response" responseTimeout="10000"/>
```

I have created a separate mule client.

```
    <client:remote-dispatcher-agent>
    <client:remote-endpoint ref="remoteDispatcherChannel" />
    <client:xml-wire-format/>
</client:remote-dispatcher-agent>


<http:endpoint name="remoteDispatcherChannel" 
               host="localhost"
               port="20809"
               path="_remoting"
               exchange-pattern="request-response" />
```

Below is the Client Code.  The ServiceSearch object implements all Serializable.

```
  MuleClient muleClient = new MuleClient(true);
        RemoteDispatcher dispatcher2 = muleClient.getRemoteDispatcher("http://127.0.0.1:20809/_remoting");
        MuleMessage result = dispatcher2.sendToRemoteComponent("myAppServiceDelegate", ServiceSearch, msgMap);
```

Below is the Mule Service flow on the server I am trying to get into.  I am coming in on the invoker step.  I choice this step as I could sent the object directly to the service in the required format

```
  <flow name="post:/service/search:my-web-services-config" initialState="started">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Request Properties" message="Request Type: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.method'], Request Path: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path'], Request Params: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.mycompany.myapp.service.model.ServiceSearch" ignoreBadInput="true" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Request JSON to ServiceSearch" />

    <invoke object-ref="myappServiceDelegate" method="processSearch" methodArguments="#[payload],#[flowVars.'CLIENT_ID']" doc:name="Calling Search Delegate" />
    <logger message="Generated DSL: #[payload.queryDSL]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Query DSL" />

    <flow-ref name="BigDataSearchFlow" doc:name="Big Data Flow" />
    <exception-strategy ref="globalResponseExceptionStrategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy" />
</flow>
```

I would appreciate some feedback on this approach and suggestions on what I should look for in the ServiceSearch object.

Russ

Answer (score 0):

You are using an order/newer version of `com.mycompany.myapp.service.model.ServiceSearch` or none at all at the server side.

Please make sure both ends do have the very same version of the file.

Comment: I copied the domain objects into the client project from the server project.  They kept the original package  structure.  Nothing was changed there.

Comment: Same JVM version/architecture?

Comment: Yes.  Running on the same machine with same jdk and jre.